# ¿Cómo descargar archivo KML en Java?

Tags: java-ee, java-8, sftp, jsch

Este es el codigo que implemento para descargar el archivo desde un servidor remoto, si encuentra el archivo pero pareciera que viene vacio.

```
public InputStream mostrar(String downLoadPath,String host,String user,String pw,String file) {
        //System.out.println(downLoadPath);
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        InputStream kml = null;
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(user,host , 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");            
            session.setPassword(pw);
            session.connect();
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;  

            kml = sftpChannel.get(downLoadPath);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return kml;
    }
```

Aquí es donde lo mando al jsp pero cuando lo recibe manda un null. No se que estoy haciendo mal o si por ser un KML tenga que hacer alguna otra cosa.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

if(tipo.isEmpty()) {
                String vacio = "null";
                response.getWriter().write(vacio);
            }else if(!tipo.isEmpty()){
                if(tipo == "gsm") {
                    file = "file.kml";
                    FileReader f = new FileReader(mostrar(ruta_server,host,servUser,pw,file));
                    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
                    while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
                      System.out.println(cadena);
                      response.getWriter().write(cadena);
                    }
                    b.close();
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: No veo donde estableces la cabecera content-disposition ni el content type. Sería algo asÍ: `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"fichero.kml\"");
          response.setContentType("application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");`

Comment: Ugh acabo de ver que el mensaje es de agosto del año pasado, te enviaré la respuesta en el Delorean.